# Перенос значений из одного ListBox в другой

Tags: delphi

Нужно из `Listbox1` вырезать строки и вставить в `Listbox2`. Не получается реализовать цикл `while`.

```
  procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i:integer;
begin
i:={что-то вставить};
while {что то вставить} do
if ListBox1.Selected[i] then
   begin
     ListBox2.Items.add(ListBox1.Items[i]);
     ListBox1.Items.Delete(i);
   end;
end;
```

Нужен счетчик проверять. Как реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

спэшли фор Олег точный код

```
var

  I : Integer;

begin

For I := ListBox1.Items.Count-1 DownTo 0 Do

If ListBox1.Selected[i] Then

  Begin

     ListBox2.Items.add(ListBox1.Items[i]);

     ListBox1.Items.Delete(I);

End;

end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Что вы конкретно пытаетесь сделать с циклом?

Так как у вас будет одно совпадение. Например:

```
i:=0;
while i<ListBox1.Items.Count do
begin
   if ListBox1.Selected[i] then //в этой строчке
       begin
       ...
       end;
   inc(i);
end;
```

А значит смысла в цикле нету.

Чтобы перенести по клику выделенный элемент делайте так:

```
function... 
begin
    if ListBox1.ItemIndex >= 0 then
    begin
        //перенос 
        ListBox2.Items.add(ListBox1.Items[ListBox1.ItemIndex]);
        ListBox1.Items.Delete(ListBox1.ItemIndex);
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

и зачем там `while` если вы переносите только выделенные строки...

просто

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items.Strings[ListBox1.ItemIndex]);
ListBox1.Items.Delete(ListBox1.ItemIndex);
end;
```

все...

+еще можно сделать проверку на существующий индекс

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
Var n:integer;
begin
n:=ListBox1.ItemIndex;
if (n=-1)or(n>ListBox1.Count-1) then Exit;
ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items.Strings[n]);
ListBox1.Items.Delete(n);
end;
```

Comment: собственно, в том коде, что я указал, и нужно сделать такую проверку, только через while.

  procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i:integer;
begin
while {что то вставить} do
if ListBox1.Selected[i] then
   begin
     ListBox2.Items.add(ListBox1.Items[i]);
     ListBox1.Items.Delete(i);
   end;
i:=i+1;
end;

как то так должно выглядеть

Comment: не, я а while то зачем?=)

Comment: чтобы переносить строки в том же порядке, в каком они есть в первом ListBox. Они переносятся в обратном порядке.

Answer (score 0):

ListBox2.Items:=ListBox1.Items;
ListBox1.Clear;